# Meal planner depending date

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, calendar, velo

Im a newbie, im trying made a calendar on my website CMS (wix) able to displaying the dishes per day for the customers and only the admin and the manager are able to modify the many dishes avalible. I browsed the wix app market if an application is able of doing that and i see that it was possible to add a 3rd part : https://support.wix.com/en/article/velo-accessing-3rd-party-services-with-the-fetch-api

### Problem :

I looked for all the possibilities on the internet, but I can't find a concrete one, I am lost, I must choose which is the right solution on these 3 possibilities:

### Solution :

1. create a calendar with HTML \ CSS \ AJAX, I don't know how I could
   make a part visible for the clients, and a part for the admin
2. I succeeded creating a dynamic calendar on excel CSV with date, but
   I can't format it in html, I was told to use VBA I don't know how to
   make xmlhttprequest requests for `GET` and `POST` products
   from excel , I don't know if it's really possible.

   [image]
3. Im found a interesting "calendar slider" based to angular but I
   can't find how I could put my dishes for each day, because my
   knowledge on angular is limited :
   https://plnkr.co/edit/cyu0Op?preview

I found the script to access the products database:

```
import wixStoresBackend from 'wix-stores-backend'; 
import wixData from 'wix-data';

const WIX_STORES_PRODUCT_TABLE = 'Stores/Products';

  const getProducts = () => {
    return wixData.query(WIX_STORES_PRODUCT_TABLE)
      .find()
      .then((data) => {
         let wixInventory = data.items;
         return wixInventory
}
```

It would be really cool if we could show me the way to create this calendar, i very motivate to find a solution for this problem

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Wix has its own database system where you can reference documents from one collection to another.

One solution would be to create a calendar Collection (_id, date, product) where `product` is a reference field to the `Stores/Products` collection.

You then create a page where you display all items for a given day

This can easily be update by admin via the content manager.

Note: You'll probably have to replace the main (Wix) store pages to prevent users from ordering products from it. You probably also need to clean the cart every day so that previous carts won't include products from another day